# How to get last request date and time in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to know that when the last request has been made on server I am using `expressjs`.

How to get that date and time?

Comment: Just declare `date` variable outside of the route, and update it in each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `morgan` node module. This code down here logs all the requests to `access.log` file in the main directory. It also shows the exact **time** and **dates** *request were made*.

**To log all** the *requests to a file*

Things to do

1. Download the modules
2. Create a file called `access.log` in the directory.
3. Run the code

   ```
   //modules
   var express = require('express');
   var fs = require('fs');
   var morgan = require('morgan');
   var path = require('path');

   var app = express(); //set up the server

   // create a write stream to the file
   var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 
   'access.log'), {flags: 'a'}); 

   // setup the logger
   app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream})); //streaming 
   //it to the file

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Check the log file!')
   })

   app.listen(2222);
   ```

**To only get** the *last request* use this code. It will get date and time when a request is made, then it will log the date and time to the console.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); //set up the server
var readline = require('readline');

app.use(function(req, res, next){

var a = new Date().toLocaleString();
readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
process.stdout.write(a);
next();

});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.send('Check the log file!');
})

app.listen(2222);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
i dont want the logs, i just only want date and time of last request made.

Comment: is there any way to get only date and time @jack Delson

Comment: I am updating it just a sec @AbhiThakkar

Comment: thanx again @jack Delson, but can u explain  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0); is used for what purpose?