# Can we check if we are getting POST request call from another server?

Tags: node.js, express, post

I am using Express in Node JS and want to check if there is no POST request for 5 minutes so that I can send Alert.

How do we solve this? Can someone please suggest some ideas.

```
app.post('/apidata', function (request, response) {
var data = new dbData(request.body)
data.save()
  .then(_item => {
    response.send('Saved data to Database')
  })
  .catch(_err => {
    response.status(400).send('Error while saving to Database. Contact Support.')
  })
})
```

This is my post request. I need to check if this API is being called. If it is not called for more than 5 minutes, I need to send alert.

Comment: Checkout this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858363/how-to-get-last-request-date-and-time-in-express-js

Comment: @Amolpskamble Edited question. Please check.

Comment: You can alert with help of `setTimeout`. Save the id of timer in `app.locals.alertTimer` or something like this. If a new request comes kill old timer and set a new one with id saved in `app.locals`.

Comment: `setTimeout` along with `express middlware` , you can achieve what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `middleware` that makes user of `setTimeout` like below:-

```
function alertMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    clearTimeout(req.app.locals.alertTimerID);
    req.app.locals.alertTimerID = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('your message');
    }, 60 * 1000 * 5);
    next();
}
app.post('/apidata', alertMiddleware, (req,res,next) => {
  //Your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

offcourse, you can send post request back to your server using nodejs

```
step1: in your request method/function 

// everytime you receive request, save that time in database or in a file
//get current time in milliseconds

var timeInMss = new Date().getTime()
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/lastrequest.txt", timeInMss , function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
   }

   console.log("The request time was saved!");
});

Step2:
//setup cron job running every 5 minutes
// install node-cron using command npm install --save node-cron

var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
    console.log('running a task every minute');

   //first get last request time read from file  
   var fs = require('fs');

  fs.readFile("/tmp/lastrequest.txt", 'utf8', function(err, timedata) {
     //check the time in timedata data if it is more than 5 minutes   before current time, then send notification     });

   var http = require("http");

  var options = {
    host: 'youranotherserver',
  port: 80,
  path: '/serverpath',
   method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {

  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
   });

});

req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: After I receive the request, I use the data for some other purpose. But how I check that I am not receiving the request for 5 minutes?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer, all you have to do is, every time you receive request save the in file/db, then write a cron job to check last request time on every 5minutes. if the request time less than 5 minutes from current time, then send notification. i hope this will help you, please mark the answer as accepted. thanks :)